# Drools decision table: is list contains elements from other list

Tags: java, list, arraylist, drools

I need to create two rules:
if list contains elements from other list;
if list contains one element.
It's desirable to make it in one column. I use decision table. How can I do it?

Comment: @JordiCastilla I tried to use `Arrays.asList` to one element and to multiple elements, using `containsAll` method to compare, but I get error `mismatched input ''`. I've imported `java.util.Arrays`, and don't know what does this error means.

Comment: Your question is rather vague. Provide code for the fact classes and show what you have tried and explain what you try to achieve.

Comment: @laune ok, give me some minutes please.

Comment: @laune, take a look please.
http://take.ms/mJW2r

But, if drools can compare it without using Java methods, I'd like to use drools opportunities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an eval:

```
ewl: c
eval(ewl.getExList().containsAll(Arrays.asList($param)))
-- check ... --
"firstElement"
"second","third","fourth"
```

There is no Drools operator for set or list operations. But you could implement a custom operator.

Adding a method to EntityWithList would simplify the expression.

Edit: Inserted Arrays.asList

Comment: Thanks, but can I do it without functions? And `Arrays.asList` gives me error `mismatched input ''`, although I imported `java.util.List` and `java.util.Array`

Comment: EDited my answer to avoid the function.

Comment: No, i need to create a list from this elements, cause `containsAll` taking only `Collection` element.